# Evenly spaced tabs in Visual Studio for formatting parameters and alike

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-formatting

I have no idea what keywords I can use to search for a solution to my question, hence I post it here.

Please see the following code.

```
        CallMyPet("Tiger", 145, "New Guinnea", Color.Orange);
        CallMyPet("Elephant", 1102, "Antwerp", Color.Grey);
        CallMyPet("Dog", 45, "London", Color.Black);
```

I like it to be formmatted as this

```
        CallMyPet("Tiger",    145,  "New Guinnea", Color.Orange);
        CallMyPet("Elephant", 1102, "Antwerp",     Color.Grey);
        CallMyPet("Dog",      45,   "London",      Color.Black);
```

Is there a function in Visual Studio (2013) or a plugin/extension that does this formatting for me?

I find this especially useful when using <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> to select blocks of text. For refactoring and such.

Comment: I would search visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com. Would something like that https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5fccd962-9fda-4b1b-9154-bb03a2568d3e work?

Comment: Such formatting will be undone again when you reformat the text.  Methods with too many arguments is not a good idea any, write declarations instead.

Comment: You seem to believe that your formatting looks nicer but what if the strings get larger? Best forget the idea..!

Comment: @TaW What if... I have don't think that I encountered such a situation past years. Do you foresee a situation where the name of the animal suddenly gets that much larger?

Comment: @HansPassant I never use auto reformat code. Only use the formatter while writing code. Could you point to an example of how those declarations look like? Do you mean a format like XML, JSON,... ?

Comment: Code Alignment Extension ( https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/7179e851-a263-44b7-a177-1d31e33c84fd) is close, but it doesn't align multiple columns on multiple lines, only two columns, so to say.